# Why does git worktree add create a branch, and can I delete it?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I used `git worktree add` to create a new worktree. I noticed that is has created a new branch in the repo with the same name as the worktree. What is this branch for?

I have checked out an other, pre-existing branch in the second worktree. Am I free to delete the branch that `git worktree add` created?

Comment: I could be wrong, but my guess is that this branch is what you are actually on while working in the worktree.

Comment: I think I should have specified the pre-existing branch I wanted to check out when I created the worktree, instead of switching branch afterwards. Then I would have avoided creating a new branch.

Comment: I can't really say *why* they did it this way, but yes, you must specify a branch for the new work-tree, so they default to having it *create* a branch named the same as the new work-tree. They could have had `git worktree add /path/to/foo` fail without a `-b` or `-B` or final argument, instead of defaulting to using `foo` here, but my guess is they thought it was more convenient to default to using `foo` here.

Comment: If you don't want to create a new branch, you can run `git worktree add --detach </path/to/worktree>` and you will get a detached head instead. This is what I always do. If you are planning to checkout some existing branch, you can do `git worktree add </path/to/worktree> <my-branch>`.

Comment: Note: for deleting worktree-related element: `git worktree --remove` (for Git 2.17+, Q2 2018): see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331132/6309)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The branch is necessary because you cannot have the same branch checked out in different worktrees at the same time.

So if you do not specify a branch when adding the worktree, then git will add one automatically, based on your current branch and with the name of the worktree directory.

You may ask, why cannot I have the same branch checkout out twice? Think of what will happen to worktree A when you commit to B, if they both share the branch... the worktree A will see the commit in B as a local difference, but in reverse! just as if you did `git reset --soft HEAD^`... That would be quite dangerous.

BTW, that is the same reason why you cannot *push to* a branch of a non-bare repository that is checked out.

About your last question: can you delete the branch? Of course, that branch is in no way special. You can delete it as long as it is not checked out anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I asked about the double checkout issue separately in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665570/why-can-two-git-worktrees-not-check-out-the-same-branch

Answer (score 56):

As the other guys answer this question, I put commands to delete the `folder`, delete `worktree` and delete `branch` here:

first, list all of your worktrees to double check...

```
$ git worktree list
```

then, delete the folder of the worktree

```
$ rm -rf path/to/worktree
```

after that, delete the worktree itself

```
$ git worktree prune
```

in case you have more than one worktree, the above command only prune the worktree that its path doesn't exist anymore, so don't worry!

finally, delete the branch (same branch-name as the worktree)

```
$ git branch -D <branch-name>
```

Comment: A worktree doesn't necessarily go with it's own branch. So it's worth to add a reservation to the recommendation to delete the branch

Comment: After I did the `rm -rf path/to/worktree` and `git worktree prune` then the `/.git/worktree` directory I had got deleted. This is expected

Answer (score 18):

From Git 2.17.0, you can safely run this all-in-one command

```
git worktree remove <path>
```

Comment: That is Sweet 

Answer (score 4):

Seems you can run in detached mode with `--detach`, which won't create branches. This may be useful if you don't plan to do modifications in the worktree, but just run build or run tests for example.

Source:
https://stacktoheap.com/blog/2016/01/19/using-multiple-worktrees-with-git/#long-running-tasks

Answer (score 3):

git worktree --help clearly mentions this as below.

```
COMMANDS
       add <path> [<branch>]
           Create <path> and checkout <branch> into it. The new working directory is linked to the current repository, sharing everything
           except working directory specific files such as HEAD, index, etc.

           If <branch> is omitted and neither -b nor -B is used, then, as a convenience, a new branch based at HEAD is created automatically,
           as if -b $(basename <path>) was specified.

       prune
           Prune working tree information in $GIT_DIR/worktrees.
```

Answer (score 3):

[`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) will add a new branch if none are specified:

> If `<commit-ish>` is omitted and neither `-b` nor `-B` nor `--detach` used,
>   then, as a convenience, a new branch based at HEAD is created automatically,
>   as if `-b $(basename <path>)` was specified.

[Since Git 2.17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc73385cf6c5c229458775bc92e7dbbe24d11611), you can delete that branch with [`git worktree remove`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-worktree.txt#L91-L96).

But, that same `remove` command also included:

> Unclean working trees or ones with submodules can be removed with `--force`.
>   The main working tree cannot be removed.

True... except `--force` was not *fully* implemented in Git 2.17.

With Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), "`git worktree remove`" learned that "`-f`" is a shorthand for "`--force`" option, just like for "git worktree add".

See [commit d228eea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d228eea5146540b09376f90e2b805553cdc78590) (17 Apr 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
Helped-by: [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 90186fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90186fa0579e4dcdde08a2d823d9b269578d5a70), 08 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `worktree`: accept `-f` as short for `--force` for removal
>
> Many commands support a "`--force`" option, frequently abbreviated as
>   "`-f`".
>   However, "`git worktree remove`"'s hand-rolled `OPT_BOOL` forgets
>   to recognize the short form, despite `git-worktree.txt` documenting
>   "`-f`" as supported.
>   Replace `OPT_BOOL` with `OPT__FORCE`, which provides "`-f`" for free, and makes '`remove`' consistent with '`add`' option parsing (which also specifies the `PARSE_OPT_NOCOMPLETE` flag).