# How to delete a git working tree branch when its working directory has been removed?

Tags: git

I've removed its working directory, because this git working tree is no longer useful, then I `git branch -D pubsub-sketch-tree` at the directory of main repository. An error thrown:

```
error: Cannot delete branch 'pubsub-sketch-tree' checked out at '/Users/zhouhancheng/编程/github_own/sketch_worktree/pubsub-sketch_tree'
```

But '/Users/zhouhancheng/编程/github_own/sketch_worktree/pubsub-sketch_tree' had been removed.

Comment: With Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), `git worktree remove` will work. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331132/6309)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are using `git worktree`, so the answer is in [the `git worktree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-worktree.html):

> When you are done with a linked working tree you can simply delete it. The working tree’s administrative files in the repository (see "DETAILS" below) will eventually be removed automatically (see `gc.worktreePruneExpire` in [git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)), or ***you can run `git worktree prune` in the main or any linked working tree*** to clean up any stale administrative files.

(emphasis mine).  Git won't let you delete the branch if it believes it is checked out in a secondary worktree.  If the secondary worktree is already removed, but Git has not yet caught on to that fact, just run `git worktree prune` to *tell* Git to go check.

Answer (score 14):

> I've removed its working directory

You will have an easier time with Git 2.17+ (Q2 2018), since "`git worktree`" has learned '`move`' and '`remove`' subcommands.

See [commit 7f19def](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f19def0fc254829839495f7fb44a7d99b161d3d) (04 Mar 2018) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
See [commit ee6763a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee6763af0a3b97225803c6c908a29de40336cf38), [commit cc73385](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc73385cf6c5c229458775bc92e7dbbe24d11611), [commit 78d986b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78d986b252359351a579dc2629c8384d5c8eb8ff), [commit c64a8d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c64a8d200f4109df86c6d4716ea4da58df450e34), [commit 9f792bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f792bb4721066ce27ee98c4ad38d6d146b64fcf), [commit 9c620fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c620fc7a60c64e183a661f4df4f7b9e25501099) (12 Feb 2018), and [commit 4ddddc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ddddc1f1d763d3c4e0e57af1153c6d48ca4db9b) (24 Jan 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bd0f794](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd0f794342d5b3921f2d5d4bffce87ec7b7e4d96), 14 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### `worktree remove`: new command
>
> This command allows to delete a worktree. Like 'move' you cannot
>   remove the main worktree, or one with submodules inside.
>
> For deleting `$GIT_WORK_TREE`, Untracked files or any staged entries are
>   considered precious and therefore prevent removal by default. Ignored
>   files are not precious.

---

> ### worktree remove: allow it when `$GIT_WORK_TREE` is already gone

"`git worktree remove`" basically consists of two things

> - delete `$GIT_WORK_TREE`
> - delete `$GIT_DIR` (which is `$SUPER_GIT_DIR/worktrees/something`)
>
> **If `$GIT_WORK_TREE` is already gone for some reason, we should be able
>   to finish the job by deleting `$GIT_DIR`**.

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was because a rebase was in progress. I switched to the branch I wanted to remove and then aborted the rebase and then I was able to delete it.

```bash
git branch {branch-to-delete}
git rebase --abort 
# or
git merge --abort

git branch main
git branch -D {branch-to-delete}
```

Comment: This is not maybe the solution they want, but because of your answer I realized that I had a rebase in progress too and that solve the issues I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to do `git bisect reset`