# Git worktree prune - what it does?

Tags: git

I'm using *git version 2.14.2.windows.2* and invoked

```
git worktree add <newpath> <branch>
```

on a "normal" repository to create a worktree. This created a new working tree structure at `<newpath>` for the branch `<branch>` and added `.git/worktrees/<newpath-name>` with a couple of files.

When invoking

```
git worktree prune
```

from the `<newpath>` it prints nothing and seems to do nothing (all the files in `<newpath>` and `<original-dir>/.git/worktrees` are kept). The [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) writes:

> Prune working tree information in $GIT_DIR/worktrees.

which does not help much. What actually `git worktree prune` does or should do? Am I wrong in the assumption that it would remove the worktree to undo the `git worktree add`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`git worktree prune` removes information about (non-locked) worktrees which no longer exist. For example,

```
$ mkdir a
$ cd a
$ git init
$ git commit --allow-empty --allow-empty-message -m ''
$ git worktree add ../b
$ ls .git/worktrees/
b
$ rm -rf ../b
$ git worktree prune
$ ls .git/worktrees/
$
```

Comment: Ah, so to remove a worktree, we just have to remove the working tree and then invoke `git worktree prune` on the worktree's original repository.

Comment: @ThomasS. Actually, with Git 2.17+ (Q2 2018), `git worktree remove` will be enough: See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331132/6309).