# Visual Studio cannot delete local branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio 2022 (17.5.3) won't let me delete a local branch because it still thinks it is checked out in a local reposititory.
However that repository does not exist anymore, the whole folder is gone. I deleted it and didn't think about the branch. The repository also doesn't show up in Visual Studio anymore. Except for the error message.

How can I fix this? Is there any other hidden or temp directory where Visual Studio stores the info?
Is there any command I can run?

I tried various, even recreated the folder but ovbiously git fails because it doesnt detect any repository anymore, since the files are gone...

Comment: In the directory of the solution file there is a hidden .vs folder you can try to delete and see if that resolves it.

Comment: @TimothyG. I don't even have a solution open.

Comment: @VonC sry I didnt mean to, that was just my saussage fingers on my smartphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error message is similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54262245/6309) (`error: Cannot delete branch 'aBranchName' checked out at 'C:/path/to/repo'`), then you need to check your `git status` first (outside of Visual Studio itself, in the local repository root folder)

You will see if you are in a worktree (as in "[multiple working directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)"), in which case you need to remove said working tree ([`git worktree remove`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331132/6309)).

The [OP CSharpie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1789202/csharpie) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75986694/visual-studio-cannot-delete-local-branch/76025344?noredirect=1#comment134096180_76025344):

> It was a worktree I deleted, not the repository, so I could use your command to delete that worktree in the actual repo.

Comment: "in the local repository root folder", well this is difficult, since i deleted that folder.

Comment: ah wait a second, i get what you are saying now

Comment: That did the trick. It was a worktree i deleted, not the repository, so i could use your command to delete that worktree in the actual repo.