# How do I salvage a worktree after accidentally deleting the branch

Tags: git, git-worktree

I have a Git worktree associated with a branch that was somehow deleted.

Nothing seems to work.  `git status` is reporting `Initial commit`.

I have uncommitted changes.  **How can I get things back to normal** in this worktree?

Answer (score 1):

Git attempts to prevent you from deleting branches that are currently checked out in any worktree.

However, with some versions of Git-related tools, it may be possible to delete a checked-out branch (I have done it while using `gitk` launched from a different worktree).  If this happens, the worktree will become confused and you will see message like `unknown revision HEAD` and `bad revision 'HEAD'`.  Normal recovery tools such as `gitk --all` and `git stash` become disfunctional due to this confusion.

Your best bet for salvaging the worktree (especially in case you have uncommitted work) is to **perform a checkout of the exact revision that was previously associated with the branch**.  One way to enable this is to run `gitk --reflog` (which works even though `gitk --all` does not) and recreate the branch at the correct location.

Once you have recreated the branch, you can check it out and resume your work.

---

Of interest: [Why does git worktree add create a branch, and can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707402/why-does-git-worktree-add-create-a-branch-and-can-i-delete-it)